# skip_comfirmation! is not working - Rails4 - Devise 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

Windows 8.1
Ruby 2.0.0
Rails 4.1
Devise 3.xx

In my registrations_controller, I have the following:

```
@user.skip_confirmation!
```

prior to saving. This is working only partially, as confirmation email is not being sent out, but the confirmed_at field is being filled, and I can login using the credentials I used to register.

How do I skip confirmation altogether? If there are recommendations on how to confirm later (by an admin), that would be great.

Comment: What behaviour do you want?  You mention that you can login using the credentials.  Do you not want this to be possible? i.e. they can't log in until the admin confirms later?  Or do you want them to be able to log in in the meantime; you just don't want the confirmed_at field set and you want the admin to be able to confirm later for some reason?

Comment: I don't want them to be able to login until they are confirmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't want them to be able to login until they've later been confirmed by an admin, you can use `skip_confirmation_notification!` instead of `skip_confirmation!`. This will create the confirmation token and the user will need to be confirmed, but it won't send the email notification to enable them to confirm themselves.  They won't be able to log in until they're confirmed.  You can then call `user.confirm!` for an admin to confirm the user later.  This should do the job, but the source code/comments might be worth a browse:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb